# How can I replicate the following input layout with Bootstrap 5?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

This is my original design:

```html
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>



<div class="card bg-dark text-white text-center mb-4">
    <div class="card-body">
        <form>
            <label>Amplitude</label>
            <input id="sldAmplitude" type="range" min="0" max="20">
            <input type="number" id="iptAmplitude" style="width: 2.5em" value="20">
            <label>cm</label>
        </form>
        <form>
            <label id="lblAmplitude">10 cm</label>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm rewriting my site for Bootstrap 5 so it also looks good on mobile but I'm having a lot of issues wit this part. Here's one of my more sane attempts:

```html
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>



<div class="card bg-dark text-white text-center mb-4">
    <div class="card-body">
        <form>
            <label for="sldAmplitude" class="form-label">Amplitude</label>
            <input id="sldAmplitude" type="range" class="form-range" min="0" max="20">
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="iptAmplitude" style="width: 2.5em" value="20">
            <label>cm</label>
        </form>
        <form>
            <label id="lblAmplitude">10 cm</label>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas? I tried columns, containers, inputgroups, fieldsets, custom css etc.

Comment: Hi Zwarte. Maybe the best recommend at the moment is to stop creating your own form controls and use the standard Bootstrap form controls and Bootstrap Validator etc. Bootstrap is very versatile but it can quickly become a mess when we're adding our own HTML and CSS to it. You have to do it of course, or every site looks the same. But it is easy to get in a mess. Here is the forms info >> https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/overview/

Comment: As far as I know I haven't added any custom CSS or my own form controls at all? Could you please explain? I copied my controls directly from that website to make the "Bootstrap version"?